# Multiplication, Division, Substraction and Addition in same Assembly Language Program

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Does anyone knows how can one perform all four mathematical operations (Multiplication, Division, Substraction and Addition) in a single program for 8 BIT/16 BIT operands. I am able to perform maximum three programs using AL,BL,CL,DL registers but i am unable to understand where should i store the values afterwards because AL is required for both DIV,MUL operations.

All efforts shall be appreciated if anyone could come up with a simple program or logic at least.

Code:

```
;================== Header ==================
; File:         all.asm
; Author:       Anurag Shukla
; Date:         25/02/2013
;================== Directives ==================

[BITS 16H]
[ORG 100H]

;================== Code Segment ==================
[SECTION .text]

mov al,0
mov bl,0
mov cl,0
mov dl,0
mov si,0
mov di,0
;================== Addition 
mov bp, 10H
add bp, [NUMADD]
daa

mov di, 20H
sub di, [NUMSUB]
das

mov al, 10H
mov bl, 10H
mul bl
mov [RMUL],al
mov dl,[RMUL]

mov al, 10H
mov bl, 2H
div bl


int3


[SECTION .DATA]

NUMADD: DB 10H
NUMSUB: DB 10H
RSUB: DB 0H
RSUM: DB 0H
RMUL: DB 0H
RDIV: DB 0H
```

Comment: post what you have so far

Comment: check the updated query

Comment: anyone?????? please help

Comment: So, what's the question/problem, really? You can always use more variables in the data segment if you run out of spare registers. And you can use the stack to hold intermediate results as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i really wanted to use registers directly. I know i can always store output in data segment but this time i want in regs.

Comment: You can also use stack. But really I see here no problem to solve. You can use any available 8-bit or 16-bit register: `al`, `ah`, `bl`, `bh`, `cl`, `ch`, `dl`, `dh`, `ax`, `bx`, `cx`, `dx`, `si`, `di`, `bp`. x86 is not a orthogonal instruction set (`mul`, `div`, `das`, `daa`, `aam`, `aad`, `lahf`, `sahf`, `in`, `out`, `stosb`, `movsb`, `scasb`, `cmpsb`, `shl` etc.) and therefore some instructions can only use some specific registers.

Comment: Thanks.... as it was MUL and DIV i arranged the operations accordingly and got the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your intermediate results on the stack or in some kind of buffer.

If you die to use the registers only, you still have *ECX*, *ESI*, *EDI* and *EBP* (and *ESP* in exceptional cases) handy while ultimately using *EAX*, *EDX* and *EBX* as inputs and outputs for the desired operations.

For example, if you want to have the results of all four operations after executing them sequentially, you could store *EAX + EBX* in *ECX*, *EAX - EBX* in *EBP*, *EAX x EBX* in *ESI:EDI* and simply keep *EAX / EBX* in *EDX:EAX*.

Anyways, the memory is there for the purpose of storing data, so I'd suggest sticking to it.